# Rails routes invisible prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, prefix, invisible

Hi my prefix in rails routes is invisible.

Here is my file routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/gossip/:id', to: 'gossip#show'
  get '/welcome/:user_entry', to: 'welcome#personnal'
  root 'home#show'
  get '/team', to: 'team#show'
  get '/contact', to: 'contact#show'
 end
```

And when i run rails routes in terminal i see that :

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                          GET  /gossip/:id(.:format)                                                                    gossip#show
                          GET  /welcome/:user_entry(.:format)                                                           welcome#personnal
                     root GET  /                                                                                        home#show
                     team GET  /team(.:format)                                                                          team#show
                  contact GET  /contact(.:format)                                                                       contact#show
       rails_service_blob GET  /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET  /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
       rails_disk_service GET  /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
update_rails_disk_service PUT  /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
     rails_direct_uploads POST /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

If i remove the `:` before `id` i see the prefix but my routes is not anymore dynamic. Any tips? thanks

Comment: What do you mean your prefix is invisible? Which line is different than what you expect? What exactly do you expect?

Comment: I need the prefix to use it in `<%= link_to "click here", prefix_path %>` ?

Comment: Are you only ever going to `show` a `gossip`? What about `new`, `create`, etc.?

Comment: For the moment i just have gossips in datbase i display all the title in a page and i want une page per gossips with the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the route named by adding `as: :some_route_name`:

```rb
get '/gossip/:id', to: 'gossip#show', as: :gossip
```

or use:

```rb
resources :gossip, only: [:show]
```

Comment: I try but to use `<%= link_to "click here", gossip_path(@id) %>` I can not use it and i don't really understabnd how to make a dynamic link maybe

Comment: @FFouquet42 try with `resources`, also make sure `@id` is not `nil`

Comment: where use `resources` in shell ? in code ? I don't know what is it and how that worked

Comment: @FFouquet42 in routes (see updated answer), more in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default